# Fluent NHibernate 1.2 + NHibernate 3.0, specify table name Options

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate, and am currently doing my first project. Say I have a very simple table named "User", it has columns of

> UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password.

And I created an entity class:

```
    public class UserAccount { 
            public virtual int? UserID { 
                    get; 
                    private set; 
            } 


            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter username.")] 
            public virtual string Username { 
                    get; 
                    private set; 
            } 


            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password.")] 
            public virtual string Password { 
                    get; 
                    private set; 
            } 


            public virtual string FirstName { 
                    get; 
                    private set; 
            } 


            public virtual string LastName { 
                    get; 
                    private set; 
            } 
    }
```

I also created mapping class:

```
    public class UserAccountMap : ClassMap<UserAccount> { 
            public UserAccountMap() { 
                    Table("User"); 
                    Id(x => x.UserID, "UserID"); 
                    Map(x => x.FirstName, "FirstName").Length(50) 
                            .Not.Nullable(); 
                    Map(x => x.LastName, "LastName").Length(50) 
                            .Not.Nullable(); 
                    Map(x => x.Username, "UserName").Length(50) 
                            .Not.Nullable(); 
                    Map(x => x.Password, "Password").Length(50) 
                            .Not.Nullable(); 
            } 
    }
```

Here I try to map UserAccount object to User table.

This is my configuration:

```
            private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory() { 
                    return Fluently.Configure() 
                            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008 
                                    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("TestDB")) 
                                    .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().UseMinimalPuts()) 
                                    .DefaultSchema("dbo") 
                                    .ShowSql()) 
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserAccount>()) 
                            .BuildSessionFactory(); 


            }
```

And this is my method to select from database:

```
                    using (var session = CreateSessionFactory()) { 
                            var query = from a in session.QueryOver<UserAccount>() 
                                                    where a.Username == "myusername" 
                                                    select a; 

                            var oneAccount = query.SingleOrDefault(); 

                            return oneAccount; 
                    }
```

But when I run the application, I got exception message:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was unhandled Message=could not execute query 
[ SELECT this_.UserID as UserID0_0_, this_.FirstName as FirstName0_0_, 
this_.LastName as LastName0_0_, this_.UserName as UserName0_0_, 
this_.Password as Password0_0_ FROM [UserAccount] this_ WHERE 
this_.UserName = @p0 ] 
Positional parameters:  #0>myusername 
.... 
  Source=NHibernate 
.... 
Message=Invalid object name 'UserAccount'.
```

It looks like I have not successfully mapped class to table name. Any clue why is that?

Comment: My first thought was that maybe it's related to the fact that USER is a reserved keyword in T-SQL but in the generated SQL the table name is inside [] so that seems to be handled. Two small things about the select method:
1. It looks like the session variable is actually a SessionFactory.
2. You are calling session.QueryOver() but I think you mean session.Query().

Comment: Also, try adding a call to ExportTo("some directory") after AddFromAssemblyOf() when configuring the session factory. This will dump out hbm files so you can check what table the entity is really mapped to.

Comment: Hi Yhrn, something funnier happened. I tried ISession.Query() and no luck. I added ExportTo() in mapping, it does not generate any hbm.xml file. I even tried to deliberately map column name to incorrect name, but from exception message I still see correct column name. I think I am really lost here.